# Virtualnetwork with virtualbox

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox

I would like to test a firewall solution. For that i would like to create a virtual network, without contact with my network and configure two virtual ethernet cards in my firewall. is that possible? say that my virtual machine has two ethernets? If with virtualbox is not possible, is it possible with any VM solution? To create virtual network and virtual devices in my virtual operational system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy in VirtualBox (and most virtualization products):

When creating/configuring the new Virtual Machine, enable Network Adapters 1 and 2, and instruct them to be attached to "Internal Network". If you give the same value for the internal network name, the cards will be attached to the same virtual switch. This will completely sandbox the network access for the VM.

You can also do the same through the command line:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <VM Name> --nic<x> intnet
```

[image]